# Rails select_tag - Setting include_blank and selecting a default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

```
select_tag :country_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.order('priority desc, name asc'), "id", "name"), { :prompt => 'Select a country', :include_blank => 'None' } %>
```

Does as expected, except `:include_blank => 'None'`. Renders an blank option. Like such:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Second, with the `select_tag`. How do I specify a default value. For example, if I need the select box to select a specific country. I tried adding `:selected => Country.first` to no avail:

```
<%= select_tag :country_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Country.order('priority desc, name asc'), "id", "name"), { :prompt => 'Select` a country', :include_blank => 'None', :selected => Country.first } %>
```

Above always selects "Select a country".

Why?

Answer (score 3):

### Blank Value

I don't think this is getting enough attention on other posts:

**`include_blank` on a `select_tag` does not respect the string passed to it. It only interprets it as a `true`/`false` value.**

In order to set a blank value for `select_tag` with a specific string, you need to use `prompt`.

### Selected Value

Because `select_tag` does not belong to a object, the way `select` does, you need to specify the selected value as part of the options.  pass the selected value into the `options` param of the `select_tag`.

In your case, you are using `options_from_collection_for_select` to help generate those options. This method takes a **fourth parameter** that specifies which option should be selected.

```
options_from_collection_for_select( 
  Country.order('priority desc, name asc'), 
  :id, 
  :name,
  Country.find_by_name('Canada')
)
```